# kie server response handling

Tags: drools, kie-server

I'm getting below error when I tried to hit kie server from java application

> Exception in thread "main" 
>   org.kie.server.client.KieServicesException:    Error while creating
>   service  response!   The actual result type class
>   org.kie.server.api.model.KieContainerResourceList     does not match
>   the         expected type class
>   org.kie.server.api.model.KieServerInfo!

Can anyone please help me in resolving this
    Getting error at below location in my code :

```
 KieServicesClient client = KieServicesFactory.newKieServicesClient(config);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you are using REST transport protocol in Kie server client.

It seems that you put wrong server URL parameter to your instance of KieServicesConfiguration. Correct URL looks like this:

> http://<server>:<port>/<context>/services/rest/server

Your server URL seems to be:

> http://<server>:<port>/<context>/services/rest/server/containers

Which is actually URL of endpoint for retrieving containers list in Kie server.